# How can I transfer a website from one Xampp to another on the same computer through folder?

Tags: xampp

I made a website and suddenly I got a Xampp error (MySQL). I tried to fix the error by watching a couple of youtube videos but it got worst. 
So I installed new xampp on another drive. But now I cannot understand how can I move my website from old xampp to the new xampp. Please help me out to move my entire website from old to new Xampp.

I tried moving htdocs website folder and MySQL database from old to new xampp but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - `but it didn't work` What do you mean by this? You need to give more of an explanation if you can...what didn't work? Any errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: I am getting this error: Error:
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

And I have tried Deleting 'ibdata1' file and restarting xamp but it does not work. I have also tried changing ports and uninstalling skype and other apps, but no luck with that too.